# Using apache2 and jetty listening on 2 IP aliases?

Tags: apache2, jetty

My ubuntu 12.04 server has been configured with two IP aliases:
eth0:0 xxx.xxx.xxx.138
and eth0:1 xxx.xxx.xxx.145
I would like to serve the two IP addresses by two different applications:
jetty web application listening on the eth0:0
apache2 web site on the eth0:1
Is that possible?
If I start jetty on eth0:1 address it works fine as long as apache2 is stopped.
When I start apache 2 I get the following:

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                              

    apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxx.xxx.xxx.138 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address xxx.xxx.xxx.145:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Apache2 configuration is the standard one with the listening directive containing xxx.xxx.xxx.145:

port.conf:

```
#NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.145:80
Listen xxx.xxx.xxx.145:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen xxx.xxx.xxx.145:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen xxx.xxx.xxx.145:443
</IfModule>
```

000-default

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.145:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mquagliani
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
 <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

On jetty side, I have the context mtc.xml containing

```
<Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>www.mindthecheck.com</Item>
      <Item>xxx.xxx.xxx.138</Item>
      <Item>localhost</Item>
      <Item>127.0.0.1</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
```

Where am I wrong? I don't want to have apache be the proxy because that will slow the jetty application. I just want jetty and apache listening from two different IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

set the ip you want to listen to for the connector in the jetty.xml, I suspect you are listening on all interfaces right now

Comment: I will look at it, but that would explain the "Address already in use" Apache error, right? Why apache is complaining also to the other address (xxx.xxx.xxx.138, the one apache has not reference in the config files)?

Comment: sure, if jetty is coming up on port X for all interfaces then no one else would be able to open that port on any of the interfaces

Comment: Done. The ERROR 98 (Address already in use) disppeared and apache can start, BUT the warning "apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxx.xxx.xxx.138 for ServerName" is still there. As I asked before, why apache complains on x.138 (only jetty listens to it) if it should listen only to x.145 ?

Comment: sorry, I can only speak to the jetty side of the coin, suspect it is something similar in apache, or just a handy 'warning' of a potential misconfiguration on their part

Comment: I searched through the apache2 directory for x.138 but I haven't found anything. As far as I knew, using the Listening directive should be enough but maybe it is not.